# how can i solve 1491 error in IDA Python?

Tags: python, ida

I'm sorry but English is not my first language.

My IDA is IDA 7.0 pro.

When I use 'Local Windows debugger' and start to debug, I get an 'internal error 1491 occur' error.

I googled the error but I can't seem to find an explanation. What raises this kind of error and how can I solve this error ?

Comment: There is a fix here but it doesn't work on every version of IDA 7 https://forum.exetools.com/showthread.php?p=119490#post119490

Answer (score 1):

Its true, there is not much information on the error but I saw this on the [changelog](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/7.0sp1/index.shtml) for 7.0sp1 which would imply that it is a bug.

I guess you should update to 7.0sp1 or later:

```
BUGFIX: windbg: ida would die with interr 1491 when debugging 32-bit windows kernel
```